# Automatic html page generagion

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a website for a customer, a car dealership website.

I have the car details on a xml file.

The problem is that I don't want to create a different file for each car.

I know how to make a "template" using php but then, the URL will not change, therefore making it impossible to share.

Is there a way I can use a "template" page and change the url?

Answer (score 1):

Use URL query strings that bind the specific data depending on the query string value.

Comment: but I have lots of information about the car... I'm not gonna put all that in the url...

Comment: No, just hold the ID of the car in the URL, then pull the XML data based on the ID of the car.